# Error handling "Can't find project or library"

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make an error handler whenever I get the error "Can't find project or library" then you deactivate the Reference to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Offfice\Office15\MSOUTL.OLB".

I'm not sure how to do this so haven't got any code yet.

EDIT: to be more specific, I want the code to work on any computer (with and without Microsoft office) so basically without me manually unchecking/checking the box in Tools>References.

```
Private Sub btnVergeten_Click()

Dim deApp As Object
Set deApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
deApp.Visible = True

Dim deMail As Object
Set deMail = deApp.createitem(deMailItem)
deMail.Visible = True

deMail.To = Worksheets("Gebruikers").Range("I2").Value
deMail.Subject = "QuedawoSoft - Kassasysteem paswoord vergeten"
deMail.Body = "De gebruikersnaam : " & Worksheets("Gebruikers").Range("E2").Value + ". Het paswoord : " & Worksheets("Gebruikers").Range("F2").Value & "."
deMail.Send

MsgBox ("De e-mail is succesvol verzonden. U zal de e-mail in een paar minuten        ontvangen.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using late binding. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/615463/how-to-avoid-references-in-vba-early-binding-vs-late-binding) or [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115)

Comment: @vacip I tried that method but seems like I didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then you need to forget about Outlook. (With or **WITHOUT** Microsoft Office means your code can't depend on Outlook.) I'm just going to give you another link, have a look at it: [rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm](http://rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm)

CDO takes a few tries to figure out, and you need to know the specifics of the mailbox you are using to send the letter from. (As in SMTP settings, etc.)

About your code:

```
Set deMail = deApp.createitem(deMailItem)
```

deMailItem makes no sense, it is supposed to be a constant, olMailItem. But if you are using late binding, you cannot use constants from the Outlook namespace. Use a 0 instead, as olMailItem=0.

```
Set deMail = deApp.createitem(0)
```

Also, the visible=true doesn't exist for neither Outlook, nor Mail items. If you want to display the mail item, use:

```
deMail.Display
```

Oh, and one more thing. You should test to see if Outlook is running, and if it already is, you shouldn't restart it, just use the existing program. See [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm).

Hope this helps!